# How to use SequenceMatcher to find similarity between two strings?

Tags: python, difflib

```
import difflib

a='abcd'
b='ab123'
seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a.lower(),b=b.lower())
seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(a,b)
d=seq.ratio()*100
print d
```

I used the above code but obtained output is 0.0. How can I get a valid answer?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You forgot the first parameter to SequenceMatcher.

```
>>> import difflib
>>> 
>>> a='abcd'
>>> b='ab123'
>>> seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a,b)
>>> d=seq.ratio()*100
>>> print d
44.4444444444
```

http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html

Comment: Hey nice answer, is there any way to get the number of matches?

Comment: get_matching_blocks()

Comment: ya i got the all the strings, but it fails to find all the common strings even if you have autojunk set to false

Comment: get_matching_blocks() literally will return a list of matching blocks. Hence, by doing len() on that list, you get the number of matches. Isn't that what you wanted? It's what you asked for.

Comment: Ya but the algorithm fails for longer length strings

Comment: Well, it's supposed to be used on source code files, really.

Answer (score 22):

From the docs:

> The [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) class has this constructor:
>
> `class difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a='', b='', autojunk=True)`

The problem in your code is that by doing

```
seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(a,b)
```

you are passing `a` as value for `isjunk` and `b` as value for `a`, leaving the default `''` value for `b`. This results in a ratio of `0.0`.

One way to overcome this (already mentioned by Lennart) is to explicitly pass `None` as extra first parameter so all the keyword arguments get assigned the correct values.

However I just found, and wanted to mention another solution, that doesn't touch the `isjunk` argument but uses the `set_seqs()` method to specify the different sequences.

```
>>> import difflib
>>> a = 'abcd'
>>> b = 'ab123'
>>> seq = difflib.SequenceMatcher()
>>> seq.set_seqs(a.lower(), b.lower())
>>> d = seq.ratio()*100
>>> print d
44.44444444444444
```